# Restart scrapy spider after unsuccessful login

Tags: python, scrapy

I've got a spider with Init function:

```
class ExpireddomainsSpider(InitSpider):
    name = "expiredomains"

    def __init__(self,typ=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExpireddomainsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.typ = typ

        users=open("users.txt","r")
        dane = self.random_line(users)
        dane = dane.split(':')
        self.user = dane[0]
        self.password = dane[1]
        self.ip = dane[2]
        self.port = dane[3]
        self.headers = {"User-Agent": dane[4]}
```

It takes a random line from tex file, where I've got user login, pass etc. Then I've got login function:

```
def login(self, response):
        self.log("USER: "+self.user+" PASS: "+self.password)
        return FormRequest('https://member.expireddomains.net/login/',
                    formdata={'login': self.user, 'password': self.password},
                    callback=self.check_login_response, method='POST')
```

And the function to check login status:

```
def check_login_response(self, response):
    sprawdz = self.user.title()
    if sprawdz in response.body:
        self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
        return scrapy.FormRequest('http://expireddomains.net/', callback=self.start_crawl)
    elif "Your account was disabled" in response.body:
        self.log("Your account was disabled!")
        super(ExpireddomainsSpider, self).__init__()
    else:
        self.log("Bad times :(")
```

Now I want to restart my spider if there was unsuccessful login. So the spider will open the file with users again and get another random line and try again.

I've tried with:

```
super(ExpireddomainsSpider, self).__init__()
```

But it doesnt work and the spider is closed.

EDIT:

Ok now I've got this:

```
class ExpireddomainsSpider(InitSpider):
    name = "expiredomains"

    def init(self):
        users=open("users.txt","r")
        dane = self.random_line(users)
        dane = dane.split(':')
        self.user = dane[0]
        self.password = dane[1]
        self.ip = dane[2]
        self.port = dane[3]
        self.headers = {"User-Agent": dane[4]}

    def __init__(self,typ=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExpireddomainsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.typ = typ
        self.init()
```

and

```
def check_login_response(self, response):
    sprawdz = self.user.title()
    if sprawdz in response.body:
        self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
        return scrapy.FormRequest('http://expireddomains.net/', callback=self.start_crawl)
    elif "Your account was disabled" in response.body:
        self.log("Your account was disabled!")
        self.init()
        return self.login(response)
    else:
        self.log("Bad times :(")
```

But it works only twice - it gets random line, try to login if fail then again it gets random line try to login if fail spider closed. It's not tryning until login is success.

SOLUTION:
Ok I've solved it. I need to add: dont_filter=True to my login function:

```
def login(self, response):
        return FormRequest('https://member.expireddomains.net/login/',
                    formdata={'login': self.user, 'password': self.password},
                    callback=self.check_login_response, method='POST',dont_filter=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move out your initialization code into its own `_init` method and then call `self.login` again. I would change `check_login_response` like:

```
def check_login_response(self, response):
    sprawdz = self.user.title()
    if sprawdz in response.body:
        self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
        return scrapy.FormRequest('http://expireddomains.net/', callback=self.start_crawl)
    elif "Your account was disabled" in response.body:
        self.log("Your account was disabled!")
        self.init()
        return self.login(response)
    else:
        self.log("Bad times :(")
```

Comment: Now it's working but not completly. I've posted an edit.